# MS SQL, how to get summary parameter by the time periods (hours) during time period (each work day)

Tags: sql, sql-server

MS SQL 2014.
At the plant 2 work shifts of 12 hours each. I need to create a statistics table, with the columns of `time`, `work shift`, `bunker number` and the `weight` of products in each bunker (kg).

For example:

```
      DateTime                      Shift Bunker    Weight
>     2018-02-25 12:43:50.9480000   1     1         123     
>     2018-02-25 13:57:49.3300000   1     2         200         
>     2018-02-25 15:21:15.2970000   1     2         100 
>     2018-02-25 01:57:49.3300000   2     1         345         
>     2018-02-25 02:21:15.2970000   2     1         55          
>     2018-02-26 13:56:02.5570000   1     1         561           
>     2018-02-26 14:57:49.3300000   1     2         254
>     2018-02-26 03:57:49.3300000   2     2         400
>     2018-02-26 05:57:49.3300000   2     2         200
```

How to make a query to output the total weight of products in each bunker for each working shift, for each day? Like this:

```
      DateTime                              Shift    Bunker     Weight
>     2018-02-25                                1     1         123     
>     2018-02-25                                1     2         300
>     2018-02-25                                2     1         400
>     2018-02-26                                1     1         561
>     2018-02-26                                1     2         254
>     2018-02-26                                2     2         600
```

This is more than my capabilities in SQL ( Thanks.

Comment: Try 
`sum(Weight)
     group by cast (Datetime as date), Shift, Bunker`

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a `GROUP BY` on Date part of the DateTime column along with Shift and Bunker.

Following query should give your the desired output.

```
SELECT  CAST([DATETIME] AS DATE) AS [DateTime], [Shift],[Bunker] ,SUM([Weight]) AS [Weight]
FROM [TABLE_NAME]
GROUP BY CAST([DATETIME] AS DATE), [Shift], [Bunker]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select CONVERT(date,datetime),shift,bunker,sum(Weight) as Weight
from table1 group by CONVERT(date,datetime),shift,bunker
```